# Why my JavaFX TableView is empty

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I added default TEST1 and TEST2 as Name Col in TableView but didn't display when I run it.
Here are two classes and one fxml I used for, can anyone give me some advices regarding this issue ?

only one package call : controllerJBoxFXTest

1st Class MainView.class
    package controllerJBoxFXTest;

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainView extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Application.launch(MainView.class, (java.lang.String[]) null);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        try {
            AnchorPane Page = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(MainView.class.getResource("MainController.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(Page);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Test Main");
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Logger.getLogger(MainView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }
}
```

2nd MainController.java, you can see I added TEST1 and TEST2 
    package controllerJBoxFXTest;

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class MainController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    TableView<Table> tableID;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Table, String> iName;

    public class Table {
        private final SimpleStringProperty rName; 
        public Table(String sName) {    
            this.rName = new SimpleStringProperty(sName);
        }
        public String getName(){ 
            return rName.get();
        }
        public void setName(String vName) { 
            this.rName.set(vName); 
        }
    }

    final ObservableList<Table> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Table("TEST1"),
            new Table("TEST2")
    );

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        iName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("rName"));
        tableID.setItems(data);
    }
}
```

3rd This is MainController.fxml which was generated by scene generator

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controllerJBoxFXTest.MainController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.8729096989966555" layoutX="197.0" layoutY="61.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView fx:id="tableID" layoutX="224.0" layoutY="107.0" prefHeight="519.0" prefWidth="798.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn fx:id="iName" prefWidth="769.0" text="Name" />
                    </columns>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0" />
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Can anyone sure why my TableView is empty when I run the MainView.java ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value you passed to the `PropertyValueFactory` (`rName`) does not match the *property* defined in your model class `Table` by the get and set method names.

Since you passed "rName", the `PropertyValueFactory` will first look for a method called `rNameProperty()` returning an `ObservableValue<String>`. Since none exists, it will look for a method `getRName()` returning a `String`. Since that doesn't exist either, your have no value to display in the column. (See the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) for a full description.)

Either change the cell value factory:

```
iName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("name"));
```

or change the method names in the `Table` class to `getRName()` and `setRName(...)`.

Comment: Great and Very Detail answer. It point me the issue out directly. Thanks very much.